# Angular Loading Json file in database

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a json file that i have to load it in database but when i want to add the Object, i get this error

> Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

here is the code in Movie Component :

```
loadJSONFile() {
 this.dataService.loadJsonFile().subscribe(
   data => data.forEach(function(movie: Movie){
     DataService.prototype.addMovie(movie).subscribe();
   })
 )
}
```

and when i try this code :

```
this.dataService.loadJsonFile().subscribe(
  data => this.filteredMovies = data
)

console.log("filteredMovies length "+this.filteredMovies.length);

for (var i=0; i < this.filteredMovies.length;i++){
  console.log(this.filteredMovies[i]);
  this.dataService.addMovie(this.filteredMovies[i]).subscribe(
    movie => console.log(movie)
  );
}
```

nothing happen in database as the code continue to execute his lines while the observable didn't finish from getting data in filteredMovies

This is DataService :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Movie } from './model/movie.model'

@Injectable()

export class DataService {

   baseUrl: string ='http://localhost:8089/library/movie/';

constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

addMovie(movie: Movie){
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, movie);
}
loadJsonFile() {
  return this.http.get<Movie[]>("./assets/movies.json");
}
}
```

can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Can you share the `DataService` code ?

Comment: @ibenjelloun `loadJsonFile() {
    return this.http.get<Movie[]>("./assets/movies.json");
  }`

Comment: This appears to be missing the relevant code-- there's nowhere in that code trying to read a property called `post`

Comment: I'm sorry, i forgot to copy the other function fom DataService :  `addMovie(movie: Movie){
    return this.http.post<Movie>(this.baseUrl, movie);
  }`

Comment: It's probably because the context of `this` is being lost. Please edit your question to include both the `addMovie` function, and the code that is calling `addMovie`

Comment: I edit my question adding dataservice

Answer (score 0):

I Got it !!, Thank you @user184994,
I made some research and i found that `this` loses context inside the nested function, so to prevent it we need to use `bind()`

`bind()` creates a new version of the function that, when called, has the this value already set.
Note that we need to use `.bind(this)` for every nested function

This is the solution :

```
this.dataService.loadJsonFile().subscribe(
  data => data.forEach(function(movie: Movie){
    this.dataService.addMovie(movie).subscribe();
  }.bind(this), this.filteredMovies = data
)
```

You can find it in this article that explains it well : [What to do when “this” loses context](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/what-to-do-when-this-loses-context-f09664af076f)